# Android SearchBar Without Clicking Button

Tags: android, searchview

I have been trying to find the answer but maybe I am not asking google correctly so here it goes: I have a search view in my android app that has the top menu item as a search input, etc. I click the magnifier, and then textfield becomes editable for search term. How can I skip this step and make it that, when onCreate() method of my activity, the search field gets the focus automatically without the need for clicking the magnifier icon?

Here is my code:

```
    MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(SearchMedicineActivity.this);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_view, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM| MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `setIconifiedByDefault(false)` inside the `public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` should get you the result you want. If you want the keyboard to be visible, try calling `requestFocus()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

> When the SearchView is used in an ActionBar as an action view for a
>   collapsible menu item, it needs to be set to iconified by default
>   using `setIconifiedByDefault(true)`. This is the default, so nothing
>   needs to be done.
>
> If you want the search field to always be visible, then call
>   `setIconifiedByDefault(false)`.

Comment: Actually, I tried this before but it didn't work. I am even updating my question now to reflect what I tried.